# How to pass a data retrieved from DataTable to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have already been able to retrieve a data from the first column of a DataTable, to an alert on jQuery.

But now, I need to pass this data to my PHP, to use on a query in order to retrieve some data from my database.

But I am not beeing able to do this...could some one help me?

```
    <?php 

    include 'db.php';

    session_start();


      if(array_key_exists("matricula",$_COOKIE))
      {
          $_SESSION['matricula'] = $_COOKIE['matricula'];
      }

      if (array_key_exists("matricula",$_SESSION))
      {

      }
      else
      {
        echo "<script> window.location.replace('login.php') </script>";
      }
      ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Gestão Cartões Diária</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/plugins/dataTables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/sorting/currency.js" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">


        <?php 
            $query = "SELECT `funcao` FROM `tb_usuarios` WHERE `matricula`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION['matricula'])."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            if( $row['funcao'] == 'EMPREGADO')
            {
                include("layout_empregado.php");                
            }
            else
            {
                include("layout_supervisor.php");               
            }
        ?>

    </div>

        <?php
            if (isset($_POST['ano_gasto']) and isset($_POST['mes_gasto']))
            {
                $SQLSELECT = "SELECT * FROM tb_gastos_alimentacao WHERE matricula LIKE '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION['matricula'])."' AND ano LIKE'".$_POST['ano_gasto']."' AND mes LIKE '".$_POST['mes_gasto']."'"; 
            }
            else
            {
                $SQLSELECT = "SELECT * FROM tb_gastos_alimentacao WHERE matricula LIKE '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION['matricula'])."'";  
            }
        ?>

        <div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <h2>Consulta Gastos Usuário <?php echo $_SESSION['matricula'] ?></h2>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <strong>Gastos Cartão</strong>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">

            <div class="row">
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                            <div class="ibox-title">
                                <h5>Dados do Usuário <?php echo ($_SESSION['matricula']) ?></h5>
                                <div class="ibox-tools">
                                    <a class="collapse-link">
                                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ibox-content">

                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-2 form-group">
                                    <label>Matrícula</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $dados_usuario['matricula']; ?>"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-7 form-group">
                                    <label>Portador do Cartão</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $dados_usuario['nome']; ?>"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3 form-group">
                                    <label>Nº Cartão</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $dados_usuario['cartao']; ?>"/>
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-2 form-group">
                                    <label>Centro de Custos</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $dados_usuario['centro_custo']; ?>"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-7 form-group">
                                    <label>Supervisão</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $dados_usuario['supervisao']; ?>"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3 form-group">
                                    <label>Lotação</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $dados_usuario['lotacao']; ?>"/>
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-2 form-group">
                                    <label>Mês</label>
                                    <select class="form-control m-b" id="cmbMesGasto" name="mes_gasto">
                                        <option value="%">TODOS</option>
                                        <option>Janeiro</option>
                                        <option>Fevereiro</option>
                                        <option>Março</option>
                                        <option>Abril</option>
                                        <option>Maio</option>
                                        <option>Junho</option>
                                        <option>Julho</option>
                                        <option>Agosto</option>
                                        <option>Setembro</option>
                                        <option>Outubro</option>
                                        <option>Novembro</option>
                                        <option>Dezembro</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="mes_selecionado" id="mes_selecionado" value="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-2 form-group">
                                    <label>Ano</label>
                                    <select class="form-control m-b" id="cmbAnoGsto" name="ano_gasto">
                                        <option value="%">TODOS</option>
                                        <option>2015</option>
                                        <option>2016</option>
                                        <option>2017</option>
                                        <option>2018</option>
                                        <option>2019</option>
                                        <option>2020</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="ano_selecionado" id="ano_selecionado" value="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-2 form-group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="pesquisa_data" id="pesquisa_data">Buscar</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="teste" id="teste">Teste</button>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                        <div class="ibox-title">
                            <h5>Consulta aos Gastos do Usuário <?php echo ($_SESSION['matricula']) ?></h5>
                            <div class="ibox-tools">
                                <a class="collapse-link">
                                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ibox-content">

                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" id="tabela" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Data Lanc.</th>
                                <th>Núm. Trans.</th>
                                <th>Estabelecimento</th>
                                <th>Localidade</th>
                                <th>Valor</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        <?php
                            $result_set =  mysqli_query($conn,$SQLSELECT);
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set))
                            {
                        ?>

                            <tr class="gradeX">
                                <td><?php echo $row['data_lancamento']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['num_transacao']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['estabelecimento']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['localidade']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['valor']; ?></td>
                            </tr>

                            <?php
                                }
                            ?>

                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Data Lanc.</th>
                            <th>Núm. Trans.</th>
                            <th>Estabelecimento</th>
                            <th>Localidade</th>
                            <th>Valor</th>
                        </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id="btn">Click</button>
        </div>



        <?php include("rodape.php"); ?>

    <!-- Mainly scripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/jeditable/jquery.jeditable.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/dataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/sorting/currency.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Custom and plugin javascript -->
    <script src="js/inspinia.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Page-Level Scripts -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.dataTables-example').DataTable({
                dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        targets: -1,
                        data: 'Valor',
                        render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( '.', ',', 2, 'R$' )
                    }
                ],
                buttons: [
                    {extend: 'copy'},
                    {extend: 'csv'},
                    {extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile'},
                    {extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile'},
                    {extend: 'print',
                     customize: function (win){
                        $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                        $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');
                        $(win.document.body).find('table')
                            .addClass('compact')
                            .css('font-size', 'inherit');
                        }
                    }
                ]

            });

        });

    //Código para selecionar uma linha da tabela
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#tabela').DataTable();

        $('#tabela tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
            if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            }
            else {
                table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            }
            var matricula_recuperada = table.cell('.selected', 0).data();
            alert(matricula_recuperada);
        } );
    } );

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

On the last 20 lines, is where I retrieve the data from DataTable, and that is the data that I wish to pass to php.

Here is a picture of the table...

[image: Complete Tabe]

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the reason for submitting this data back to the server, but I would recommend using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). PHP is able to convert JSON into an array conveniently.

Comment: @LucaNateMahler, I'm doing my queries on php, that's why I want this data back! Could you give me an example using AJAX?

Comment: How to use AJAX is a matter of googling. Rather, I think you are worried which URL to use since your application seems to be developed within a single file. Once you set the URL, JQuery will set up a regular HTTP request for you. Just google a bit, you will understand it quickly.

Comment: OK, I posted an approach. But I have to mention that this style of coding is a bit smelly. You should consider investing time learning how to improve your code to fulfill some quality criterias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the alert and use `ajax` like:

```
var matricula_recuperada = table.cell('.selected', 0).data();

$.ajax({
  url: 'your url',
  method: 'post',
  data: {
    id: matricula_recuperada
  },
  success: function(response)
  {
    // Do what ever you want here
  }
});
```

Comment: Mayank, the code is only one page, "pagina_inicial.php", can my url be only "pagina_inicial.php"? Or I need to have my php code in other page?
I tryed to do what you said putting "pagina_inicial.php" on my url, but when I click on a row it still don't return me the data to php.

Comment: Make a separate code file for this and pass the name and its path in the url (**which is recommended**). Otherwise you can use the same file by making a code block that check in whether the `id` is set or not.

Answer (score 1):

Consider following measures which are quite straighforward:

(1) Enrich your table rows with the primary key ID of the entries in order to submit this ID back to the server later. E.g. a `data-id` attribute on your `<tr>`s:

```
<tr class="gradeX" data-entryID="<?= $row['data_id'] ?>">
```

(2) Develop an AJAX-request to submit this entry-id.

```
$('[data-entryID]').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'handleClickedEntry.php',
       data: {
          entryID: $(this).attr('data-entryID')
       },
       success: function(data) {
          // The servers response as data
       }
    });
});
```

(3) Create a PHP-file (or use an existing one, just make sure to have a unique URL) for handling what you want to do with the clicked table row. Maybe something like handleClickedEntry.php but make sure conveying the responsibility of the action.

Inside this file you will get the via AJAX submitted data as the `$_REQUEST` array. So you can access the given entry ID easily: `$_REQUEST['entryID']`.

If you want to respond with data, use the `json_encode` function to convert a PHP array back to JSON and echo it. E.g.:

```
$newData = ['entryID' => 3, 'someProperty' => 'test'];
$jsonResponse = json_encode($newData);

echo $jsonResponse;
```

This `$jsonResponse` will be the `data` variable used in the `success` function inside your AJAX-call. Use `$.parseJSON` to convert it back.

**EDIT:** If you want to use the same file for handling the click-action, adapt as following:

```
$('[data-entryID]').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'yourFile.php',
       data: {
          entryID: $(this).attr('data-entryID'),
          action: 'handleRowClick'
       },
       success: function(data) {
          // The servers response as data
       }
    });
});
```

The only thing remaining is the check if an HTTP request stems from this AJAX call:

```
if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'handleRowClick') {
    // Handle the AJAX request here
}
```

I don't recommend this at all, but in view of your solution it may fit the best.